# Javascript loop through objects in array

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I need to create a function that will look through all the properties of an object and change the values to say "redacted", then return the object.

```
var superSecret = function(spy){
  // Code Here
}
```

Comment: can you post an example of the object and the result you're expecting?

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want, either a `for..in` loop, or go over `Object.keys(yourObj)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (prop in spy) {
    spy[prop] = "redacted";
}
```

or if you instead want to return a *clone* of the object that has everything "redacted":

```
var obj = {};
for (prop in spy) {
    obj[prop] = "redacted";
}
return obj;
```

Comment: This is better than mine

Answer (score 0):

```
var superSecret = function(spy){
  Object.keys(spy).forEach(function(key){
    spy[key] = "redacted";
  }
}
```